# Препятствия удаляются быстрее, чем проходит анимация пули

Tags: java, javafx

**Ситуация**: У танка есть метод `Shot()` и в нём есть код, который проверяет: соприкасается ли пуля с препятствием после выстрела. Пуля летит вверх по X-координате. Цикл `do...while` проверяет на какое расстояние сможет пролететь пуля без препятствий. После происходит анимация полёта самой пули через `TranslateTransition`. А последний цикл проходит по всем игровым препятствиям и через `intersects` проверяет на соприкосновение и в успешном случае удаляет препятствие.

```
               do {
               y = (int) (bulletObj.getImageBullet().getTranslateX() + register) / PlayField.BRICK_SIZE;
               x = (int) bulletObj.getImageBullet().getTranslateY() / PlayField.BRICK_SIZE;
               line = LevelData.LevelOne[x][y];
               register += 1;
               } while (line.equals("0"));

                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); // 1643642047472 ms.

                bulletTranslate = new TranslateTransition();
                bulletTranslate.setFromX(bulletObj.getImageBullet().getTranslateX());
                bulletTranslate.setToX(bulletObj.getImageBullet().getTranslateX() + register - 18);
                bulletTranslate.setNode(bulletObj.getImageBullet());
                bulletTranslate.setDuration(Duration.millis(register)); // Условно пусть register = 300 мs.
                bulletTranslate.play();

                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); // 1643642047474 ms.

                bulletObj.getImageBullet().setTranslateX(bulletObj.getImageBullet().getTranslateX() + register - 18);
                for (GameObject platform: PlayField.platforms) { 
                    if (platform.getImage().getBoundsInParent().intersects(bulletObj.getImageBullet().getBoundsInParent()))
                    {

                        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); // 1643642047474 ms.
 
                        tankRoot.getChildren().remove(platform.getImage());
                        PlayField.platforms.remove(platform); 
                        LevelData.LevelOne[x][y] = "0";
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Всё работает как и требовалось, но проблема одна.

**Проблема в том, что объекты-препятствия удаляются быстрее, чем проходит анимация пули.**

**А нужно, чтобы после соприкосновения они удалялись одновременно.**

**Как решить проблему?**

*Фото:*

[До выстрела](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4giz.png)

[После выстрела, объект исчез во время полёта пули](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOUh1.png)

P.S Карта небольшая и задана через массив String-ов. Надеюсь объяснил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы работаете в одном потоке, только после того как вся область видимости этого потока, завершит своё действие, т.е тут

```
   for (GameObject platform: PlayField.platforms) { 
                if (platform.getImage().getBoundsInParent().intersects(bulletObj.getImageBullet().getBoundsInParent()))
                {

                    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); // 1643642047474 ms.

                    tankRoot.getChildren().remove(platform.getImage());
                    PlayField.platforms.remove(platform); 
                    LevelData.LevelOne[x][y] = "0";
                    break;
                }
```

Начнёт выполняться `bulletTranslate.play();`

Можно попробовать обернуть его в

`Platform.runLater(()->{bulletTranslate.play();})`

А перед тем, как выполнить remove запросить у bulletTranslate.getStatus (проверить произошла ли отрисовка до конца.

Но тогда смысл вашего движка потеряется. Т.е вы уже точно знаете что "попали" и пуля летит, но ведь теоретически, может быть так, что в процессе полёта какой-нибудь движущийся объект окажется на пути, раньше(ближе) уже удалённого объекта. К тому же, в JFX довольно трудно синхронизировать потоки, вы можете выстрелить, и пуля долелит. А объект взорвётся секунд через 5 (грубый пример). Поэтому имхо, столкновение надо отрабатывать "здесь и сейчас" и только после этого, рисовать все фанты.

P.S исходя из `bulletTranslate.setDuration(Duration.millis(register)); // Условно пусть register = 300 мs.` Скорость полёта пули всегда разной будет, что не есть хорошо. Опять же, имхо. Вы художник, вам виднее )